# Pip Install Not working with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I tried entering `pip install scikit-learn` on Python shell, I got the "invalid syntax" message. I already
have Scipy and Numpy installed so there shouldn't be any depedency issues.  What's wrong? 
And I am still new to Python so I don't want to manually install the module. I am using Python 2.7 on
Vista 32-bit.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes, I re-read your question. As I understand you youre trying to execute a pip install command from the python shell. This is not how it works. :) You have to run it from the command line. Check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you installed everything using windows executable (.exe files) you should also install this as an executable available for download here - [Scikit Learn Executables](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scikit-learn/files/)

Or,

The python shell is not the place to run `pip` commands. So open the command line terminal in windows and do `pip install -U scikit-learn`

Then go to python shell and import it.